# Not sure what to do with JSON data

Tags: java, android, json

Im making a weather application in eclipse for Android, I need to show icons describing the weather for 3 hour intervals between 1 day.

I get the API from http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Melbourne

I then use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to make in java classes(I think thats what it does anyways..)

Now I got the following code:

```
private class ForecastForHoursTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String measurement = checkMeasurement();

    private final String SERVICE_ADDRESS_START = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ForecastForHoursTask(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String serviceAddress = SERVICE_ADDRESS_START + params[0];
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serviceAddress);
        try {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String bufferString = "";
            while ((bufferString = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(bufferString);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        if (this.progressBar != null) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ImageView imgFirst = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgEightAm);
        ImageView imgSecond = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgElevenAm);
        ImageView imgThird = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTwoPm);
        ImageView imgFourth = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFivePm);
        ImageView imgFifth = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgEightPm);
        ImageView imgSixth = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgElevenPm);
        ImageView imgSeventh = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTwoAm);
        ImageView imgEighth = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFiveAm);
        TextView imgTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTest);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        NewRoot newitem = gson.fromJson(result, NewRoot.class);

        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setVisibility(-1);
    }
}
```

There are ImageView's which I want to set the icons to. But I'm stumped on what to do in the onPostExecute. I think I need sort the data so I can search for the (dt_txt) field and get the associated (icon) value so I can set ImageView to the corrosponding image by the (icon) value. 
Im stuck on how to do that.

Comment: Try using a library like Retrofit to pull down data from APIs. You don't really tell us what the error is here.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand your question.

Comment: Im not getting an error, I dont know how to get dt_txt or icon from the deserialised JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a serialization issue. The names and data types in your NewRoot class must match those that you download from the API. You can also set them with Gson annotations if you want.
Here's a great guide you should read: [link](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).